# How do I check if a Python method is running using a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to call a method and then have a while loop that runs and records data as long as the method is running. It will stop recording when the method is done running. I initially tried to use *while True: , for loop, if False: return data and break*. but got a *code unreachable* error for the *return data and break* inside the *if False* statement. I took out the if statement and now have this:

```
def recordData(memory_service):
    """ Record the data from ALMemory.
        Returns a matrix of values
    """
    print "Recording data ..."
    data = list()

    # while program is running, record data
    print "4"
    kickCall()
    while True:
        print "5"
        line = list()

        for key in ALMEMORY_KEY_NAMES:
            print "6"
            value = memory_service.getData(key)
            line.append(value)
        print "7"
        data.append(line)

        return data
# break
```

However, this only saved one line of data when there should be a lot. (The print# statements are just checks)

Here is the code output: [Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ812.png)

Code with if statement:

```
def recordData(memory_service):
    """ Record the data from ALMemory.
        Returns a matrix of values
    """
    print "Recording data ..."
    data = list()

    print "4"
    kickCall()
    while True:
        print "5"
        line = list()
        for key in ALMEMORY_KEY_NAMES:
            print "6"
            value = memory_service.getData(key)
            line.append(value)
        print "7"
        data.append(line)
        
        if False:
            print "8"
            return data
            break
            print "9"
'''
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you just need to move the return to the left. If you have a `return` in it, the loop will not be executed further. Just make sure to `break` the loop eventually.

Comment: `return data` is inside while loop. I think unindenting return statement 1 level will return your desired output

Comment: hello @thinkgruen - When I do that it highlights the return statement as "This code is unreachable"

Comment: `return` would break out of the loop on the first iteration; you need some sort of *conditional* return that would all the loop to execute more than once. (Otherwise, you don't need a loop at all.) Simply unindenting the `return` statement indeed makes it unreachable, because now *nothing* terminates the loop: the condition is always true, and there's no `break` statement to terminate it.

Comment: You need some way to determine once the program has stopped running, then break out of the loop and return only then. Can you give more information about this other program you are watching?

Comment: @spotomic I assume because the loop is infinite, everything below becomes unreachable.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into async code for this, which is a bit of a pain but should be doable

Comment: Hello @chepner - I edited the post to contain the original code where I have an if statement. everything below the if statement was labeled "code unreachable" is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @C_Z_ The code its watching is a kick method that plays out on a robot. Would adding some return at the end of the kick method and then watching for that return in the while loop work for breaking out of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an indentation problem in your first snippet. Just move the `return data` statement to the left to remove it from the while block. Other than that you don't seem to make it clear what is the condition you are watching to end the execution of the loop. I *speculate* that you want to return the data as soon as there are no more values to append to the line list. If that's the case, then this might be a solution:

```
def recordData(memory_service):
""" Record the data from ALMemory.
    Returns a matrix of values
"""
print "Recording data ..."
data = list()

# while program is running, record data
print "4"
kickCall()

while True:
    print "5"
    line = list()

    for key in ALMEMORY_KEY_NAMES:
        print "6"
        value = memory_service.getData(key)
        line.append(value)
    print "7"

    if len(line) == 0:
        break

    data.append(line)

return data
```

Beware that the conditional statement `if len(line) == 0:` could also be rewritten as `if not line:`. The reason I chose the first form was exclusively for clarity: We are evaluating if the number of elements in the `line` list is zero, not if the value referenced by the name `line` evaluates as true or false.